# Does Microsoft Power BI have file size limitations for functionality like Excel Power Query does?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I inherited an Excel data model consisting of multiple workbooks. Each workbook has multiple tabs utilizing Power Queries  to get, transform and load data sets from base supporting Excel and csv files.

Over time the files of the model have grown tremendously (upwards of 30MB) in size causing Excel to hang or crash. It has only been recently that I discovered Excel Power Query has a file size limitation of 10MB.

I am now considering a redesign of the model using Microsoft Power BI and want to know if there are any such limitations that will need to be considered.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this support article it seems that the file size is limited to 1GB:
[Power BI Increases File Size Limit from 250 MB to 1 GB](http://www.microsofttrends.com/2016/05/18/power-bi-increases-file-size-limit-from-250-mb-to-1-gb/)

Comment: That limit is only relevant to files uploaded to the web service, using a Free or Pro license.  The current limit for a Premium license is 10GB. Using Power BI Desktop, you are only limited by the RAM available on your machine.

Comment: the link is broken